# Preventing circular import example

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Lets say I have two python files. Both with an GUI. First is "Main" second is "Calculator". From Main I will start Calculator. So I have to import calculator. In Calculator I will do a calculation. Lets keep I easy an say 1+1=2. Now I want to "send" this Result to an Text in Main.

How do I do that without an circular import? I cant find an good tutorial/example for that!

My code so far:

Main:

```
from tkinter import *

import Test_2

window = Tk() 
window.title("First Window")

def start():
    Test_2.start_second()

Input1 = Entry(window)
Input1.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

Start = Button(window,text="Start", command=start)
Start.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Second:

```
from tkinter import *


def start_second():
    window2 = Tk() 
    window2.title("Second Window")

    def send():
        x = Input.get()


    Input2 = Entry(window2)
    Input2.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

    Send = Button(window2,text="Send", command=send)
    Send.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)


    window2.mainloop()
```

Comment: since you are calling a function from "Main", why not return a value and then use that value in "Main"?

Comment: Agree with @FlyingTeller. Don't send. Retrieve it from the other side. See my answer here to a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563516/correct-way-and-location-of-importing-packages/49931246#49931246

Comment: I have some problems converting your answere with my beginner knowledge to my code. I have added my code to my queston. Could you help me were I have to return the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does exactly what you asked for (as opposed to what I suggested in the comment; but anyway, you either get a value from a module function or you send a reference for it to alter)

I tried to follow your structure.

Basically it is a matter of sending the parent window and the first entry as parameters to the second window creation function. Don't call mainloop two times, just once in the end, and use `Toplevel` for all other windows after the main `Tk` one. This is not to say that I like the use of an inner function and of the `lambda`, for readability, but lambdas are necessary in tkinter everytime you want to send parameters to a command callback, otherwise it will get called right way in command definition.

`tkinter_w1.py (your main.py)`

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter_w2 import open_window_2

root = Tk()

entry1 = ttk.Entry(root)
button1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Open Window 2',
    command=lambda parent=root, entry=entry1:open_window_2(parent, entry))

entry1.pack()
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`tkinter_w2.py (your Test_2.py)`

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Toplevel
import tkinter as tk

def open_window_2(parent, entry):

    def send():
        entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        entry.insert(0,entry2.get())

    window2 = Toplevel(parent)
    entry2 = ttk.Entry(window2)
    button2 = ttk.Button(window2, text='Send', command=send)
    entry2.pack()
    button2.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also for helping me to improve my code beyond my question.